# Creating database triggers via Fluent API

Tags: sqlite, database-trigger, ef-core-2.2

I am using ef-core 2.2 in connection with sqlite. In order to prevent/catch concurrency exceptions, I am [creating a concurrency token](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/modeling/concurrency) in the according table. The token is a timestamp which I am configuring in my `DbContext` class via Fluent API:

```java
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property( u => u.Timestamp ).IsRowVersion();
```

After that I need the timestamp to be updated on every update to my table-entry, therefor I am appending a sql statement to my automatically created migration file:

In `Up( MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder )`:

```java
migrationBuilder.Sql( "CREATE TRIGGER SetUserTimestamp AFTER UPDATE ON Users BEGIN UPDATE Users SET Timestamp = randomblob( 8 ) WHERE Id = NEW.Id; END" );
```

In `Down( MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder )` I append:

```java
migrationBuilder.Sql( "DROP TRIGGER SetUserTimestamp" );
```

This solution does work well. One problem for me is that I have to be extremely careful not to forget including the trigger creation after I created a new migration via command line. Is there any way to configure this trigger in the `DbContext` class, maybe via Fluent API? Or is there another way to automate the creation of the trigger?

Comment: Currently there is not EF Core support. You have to handle it manually.